# Distribution of sample means without replacement for large samples

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, sampling, central-limit-theorem

I am starting with $N$ values drawn from a standard Normal distribution. I then sample, without replacement, every subset of size $k$, of which there are $\binom{N}{k}$, and calculate the sample mean of each subset. I've seen that for sufficiently small values of $k$, the distribution of the sample means can be approximated by a Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1/k$, which is the distribution that would result from sampling *with* replacement.

I am wondering if there are any results on the distribution of the sample means for larger $k$, such as $k = N/2$.

Comment: HInt: consider $k=N-1.$ The distribution of sample means is particularly simple to work out (because each mean is related to the value of the one number not in the sample). And be careful: to the extent the sample's distribution departs from Normality (and *all* samples are non-Normal), the distributions of these *subsample* means will depart from Normality, too.

Comment: I am more interested in values of $k$ for which $N-k$ is not sufficiently small either, such as $k = N/2$.

Comment: The hint was intended to make it obvious that such results exist and are easy to obtain for any $N$ and $k.$

Comment: It’s not obvious to me.